# Database.com Light Users and Role Hierarchy

Tags: licenses, database.com

I'm trying to figure out exactly what the differences between Light and Standard users are in database.com to figure out if it is a viable solution for something I am working on, particularly around record access. From what I can see, it seems like Light users work within the OWD and role hierarchy, and if you want anything more dynamic than that then you need to switch to Standard users. Is that correct, I can't seem to find conclusive evidence one way or another? More specifically, I can't determine if role hierarchy would fall under the "record level sharing" that the documentation refers to as required Standard Users.

http://devcenter.database.com/page/Understanding_Database.com_System_and_Data_Access_Controls